# React React setState not updating on First attempt

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to show conditionally a div on the same class components. But the state changes updates only from second click.

this is my code

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        openSignIn: false
    };
    this.handleOpenSignIn = this.handleOpenSignIn.bind(this);
}
```

setState

```
    handleOpenSignIn() {
       this.setState({ openSignIn: true });
    }
```

and i have to show an element if 'openSignIn' is true

```
<button className="nav-link px-4 border rounded-sm whiteBtn" onClick={() => this.handleOpenSignIn()}>Login</button>

{this.state.openSignIn &&
    <div>Show</div>
}
```

The div showing only click two times on the button.
am very new in React js.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      openSignIn: false
    };
    this.handleOpenSignIn = this.handleOpenSignIn.bind(this);
  }

  handleOpenSignIn() {
    this.setState({
      openSignIn: true
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          className="nav-link px-4 border rounded-sm whiteBtn"
          onClick={() => this.handleOpenSignIn()}
        >
          Login
        </button>
        {this.state.openSignIn && <div>Show</div>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

    
 ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: Not sure what u are asking ? Please explain a bit

Comment: Can you provide a codesandbox link for the same?

Comment: @JobRajan I have converted your code to a snippet and it works as is. Please try to provide [mcve] using the snippet that actually demonstrates the issue.

Comment: For me also it's working in first click.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and support. 
Now its working fine the problem was, the conditionally loading div is a bootstrap modal so the modal not showing  on first click of **handleOpenSignIn**. Its only coming on view when click on it second time. Now i changed the condition "{this.state.openSignIn &&" to inside content of modal. Then its working. Sorry for my mistake. I just only started React js and Its my first project in react js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React from 'react';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      openSignIn: false
    };
    this.handleOpenSignIn = this.handleOpenSignIn.bind(this);
  }

  handleOpenSignIn() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      openSignIn: !prevState.openSignIn
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          className="nav-link px-4 border rounded-sm whiteBtn"
          onClick={() => this.handleOpenSignIn()}
        >
          Login
        </button>
        {this.state.openSignIn && <div>Show</div>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

If you want to toggle instead of just show you can use the above code.
You should not change the boolean state as you are doing in your snippet.

Comment: Your code is introducing completely different behaviour. How is this related to the question "React React setState not updating on First attempt"? Consider the name "handleOpenSignIn" sounds like it should **open** something, not **toggle** something.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko As you see in my code the state is getting updated on the first click . ```handleOpenSignIn``` was given by the person who asked this question. I am merely stating a better way using his code snippet.

Comment: It is not better. It is different. And his code also works as-is. The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko His code works. That's right. But if that's the case then what is the problem?
Also, could you please explain to me what can I do to make my code better.

Comment: Your code is fine. There is nothing wrong with it per se. It just implements a different use case. OP's code "opens" yours - "toggles" :) And thus is not related to the question.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko
I edited the answer. I believe now it showcases what I am trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

But It works exactly..

[Open code sandbox to run your code](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-antonelli-z5xxy?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)